# Determine or Is there a way to identify if RFID/NFC is cloned?

Tags: java, android, clone, nfc

I have this capstone project in which focuses on school attendance with the use of RFID Cards. In terms of security of the RFID , is there a way to identify if the card was cloned?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no reliable way to tell if a card is cloned, other than noticing 2 identical cards existing at the same time.

Due to the relatively large UID (Unique ID) size of PC/SC compliant smart-cards (usually 128 bits), the probability that your organisation buys 2 cards with the same UID is effectively zero. Therefore, if you see 2 scans of a card with the same UID at a similar time, but separated physically by a large distance, you can be sure that one of them has been cloned.

However, without using techniques such as this, as far as I know, there are no good ways to check this in a technical sense.

Comment: I get thepoint. Since most of the cards today especially Mifare, usually used for payments.For those cards which is writable and readable , can i set that particular card to read only?